# Can I OpenGL render a quad view?

Tags: 3d-view, opengl

Is it possible to playblast (openGL render) the quad view? In quad view if I launch playblast, only 1 of the views is rendered. Am I missing something for it to work (like an option in the user preferences)?

Comment: Looks like the upper right region of the quadview is used for rendering only, this might be an oversight in the OpenGL rendering feature, or a known limitation. Please refer to the Blender bug tracker to clarify.

Comment: @CoDEmanX Thx, I'll have a look over there!

Answer (score 6):

You could fake it with 3 additional ortho cameras layered in the VSE with scale transform effects arranged in a quad display. It renders super quick.[image]